# How to start grail application in production mode without terminate session when close command windows?

Tags: java, linux, grails, groovy, centos

I have a grails 2.4.3 application run on centos 7. My problem is that I can't start the application via terminal, because when I close terminal, the session is terminated.

My command to start program is:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/setup/grails-2.4.4/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/
grails prod run-app
```

I have already try many ways: 
i.e: nohup grails prod run-app (nothing change after running command),
setsid prod run-app (program terminated by accidentally after a time running).
Both the ways are not worked. 
Please help me find a way to start Grails application in production precisely.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `grails run-app` in production. From the [Grails 2.4.4 documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/gettingStarted.html#deployingAnApplication)

> NEVER deploy Grails using the run-app command as this command sets Grails up for auto-reloading at runtime which has a severe performance and scalability implications

In Grails 2.x (for production), you need to deploy your application to a supported Java EE Container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc), which are listed on the same page in the documentation.

In Grails 3.x you can package your web app as a jar and run it like any other jar because it is built on top of Spring Boot and the container was packaged into the jar.

Comment: Thanks @dspie: I will try your suggestion by running this app on web server container. i.e: Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can use the `nohup` (no hang-up) command to make sure that the command will not be killed when you close the terminal.

Create a sh (startup.sh) file containing your startup statements:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/setup/grails-2.4.4/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/
grails prod run-app" > startup.sh
```

make sure the script is executable

```
chmod +x startup.sh
```

then

```
nohup ./startup.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis, I can start by nohup. Now I need to keep watching whether it is killed. If they still has problem, I will choose run app in web server container, i.e: Tomcat.

Comment: I'm glad it helped